# Spring boot GET and GET with parameter endpoints missing from Swagger docs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have two get mapping in rest controller, one with a required request parameter (item ID), one without request param with the same path.

Also, have a basic Swagger with UI set up in the project. At first from the 2 get mapping I described earlier one is randomly missing, then I annotated them properly with swagger annotations, but now the get without parameter constantly missing.

```
@ApiOperation("Get item with the given ID")
@GetMapping(value="/resource/item", params = "id")
public Item getOne(@ApiParam(value = "the ID of the item want to view") @RequestParam(name = "id") Long id) {
    //things...
}

@ApiOperation("Get all item")
@GetMapping(value="/resource/item")
public List<Item> getAll() {
    //things...
}
```

Is there a way to force swagger to map both get mapping?

Update:
Yes, path variable can be a good solution, but i can't do that because of legacy reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than RequestParam I would use Pathvariable

```
@ApiOperation("Get item with the given ID")
@GetMapping(value="/resource/item/{id}")
public Item getOne(@ApiParam(value = "the ID of the item want to view") @PathVariable Long id) {
    //things...
}
```

That way your mappings are different and most likely will show up in swagger.

Comment: Legacy, can't change to path variable, that was my first idea too. Moreover, the actual problem is in an abstract controller :/